# Select Options to trigger table appearance

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table with two columns. I have a select option dropdown box. I have 6 different values for the table row that correspond with a color, green being good, red being bad, and so on. What I want to accomplish is when a user loads the page all values are present. Then when the user selects a value from the dropdown box, everything BUT that value selected disappears.

My Javascript

```
 function select_mem() {
        if ($("select[name='status-type']").val() == "all") {

            $('.num-good').show();
            $('.num-not').show();
            $('.num-not-working').show();
            $('.num-bad').show();
            $('.num-blue').show();

        }
  if ($("select[name='status-type']").val() == "good") {

            $('.num-good').show();
            $('.num-not').hide();
            $('.num-not-working').hide();
            $('.num-bad').hide();
            $('.num-blue').hide();

        }
 if ($("select[name='status-type']").val() == "bad") {

            $('.num-good').hide();
            $('.num-not').hide();
            $('.num-not-working').hide();
            $('.num-bad').show();
            $('.num-blue').hie();

        }
  if ($("select[name='status-type']").val() == "not-working") {

            $('.num-good').hide();
            $('.num-not').hide();
            $('.num-not-working').show();
            $('.num-bad').hide();
            $('.num-blue').hide();

        }
 if ($("select[name='status-type']").val() == "not") {

            $('.num-good').hide();
            $('.num-not').show();
            $('.num-not-working').hide();
            $('.num-bad').hide();
            $('.num-blue').hide();

        }
 if ($("select[name='status-type']").val() == "blue") {

            $('.num-good').hide();
            $('.num-not').hide();
            $('.num-not-working').hide();
            $('.num-bad').hide();
            $('.num-blue').show();

        }

    }
```

My HTML

```
    <section class="filter">

        <p>Filter your search: <select id ="options" name="status-type" onChange="select_num()">
            <option id="all" value="all">All Numbers</option>
            <option id="good" value="good">Good Numbers</option>
            <option id="bad" value="bad">Bad Numbers</option>
            <option id="not-working" value="not-working">Not Working Numbers</option>
            <option id="not" value="not">Non Numbers</option>

        </select></p> 
    </section>

    <!-- Valid Numbers -->
    <table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Status</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr class="num-good">
    <!-- Number -->
    <td>+1 (941) 888-888</td>
    <!-- Status -->
    <td>Good</td>
</tr>
<tr class="num-good">
    <!-- Number -->
    <td>+1 (941) 888-888</td>
    <!-- Status -->
    <td>Good</td>
</tr>
<tr class="num-not">
    <!-- Number -->
    <td>+1 (941) 888-888</td>
    <!-- Status -->
    <td>Not</td>
</tr>
<tr class="num-not-working">
    <!-- Number -->
    <td>+1 (941) 888-888</td>
    <!-- Status -->
    <td>Not Working</td>
</tr>
<tr class="num-not">
    <!-- Number -->
    <td>+1 (941) 888-888</td>
    <!-- Status -->
    <td>Not</td>
</tr>
<tr class="num-bad">
    <!-- Number -->
    <td>+1 (941) 888-888</td>
    <!-- Status -->
    <td>Bad</td>
</tr>
<tr class="num-bad">
    <!-- Number -->
    <td>+1 (941) 888-888</td>
    <!-- Status -->
    <td>Bad</td>
</tr>
<tr class="">
    <!-- Number -->
    <td>+1 (941) 888-888</td>
    <!-- Status -->
    <td>Not a number</td>
</tr>
<tr class="blue">
    <!-- Number -->
    <td>+1 (941) 888-888</td>
    <!-- Status -->
    <td>Blue</td>
</tr>
<tr class="blue">
    <!-- Number -->
    <td>+1 (941) 888-888</td>
    <!-- Status -->
    <td>Blue</td>
</tr>
<tr class="num-good">
    <!-- Number -->
    <td>+1 (941) 888-888</td>
    <!-- Status -->
    <td>Good</td>
</tr>


</tbody>
```

My current code can be found on jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hodhLyw1/1/

I'm trying to use jQuery, but if there is a better way to do it in pure Javascript I would prefer that. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Well for starters, you call select_num() on your onChange, while your actual function is called select_mem().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can simplify all your repetitive code down into something like:

```
var $rows = $('tbody tr'); // cache all the table rows

$("select[name='status-type']").change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();  // get current value
    if( val == 'all'){
       $rows.show(); 
    }else{
       // hide all then show ones that match filter class
       $rows.hide().filter('.num-' + val).show();
    }
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/czLyxcvn/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

A CSS selector like `$("select[name='status-type']")` can be replaced with `document.querySelector("select[name='status-type']")`. Then `.val()` can be written as `.value` in vanilla.

There are several ways to show and hide elements, the simplest is `myElement.hidden = false` or `myElement.hidden = true`. You could also add a class with `myElement.classList.add('myclass')` (similar to jQuery's `myElement.addClass()`) and remove it with `classList.remove()`.

You can learn more about vanilla DOM manipulation on [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/API).